# How to use MASM within DOSBox or any other DOS emulator?

Tags: macos, ubuntu, mac, dosbox

I have DOSBox installed and I am trying to use MASM from  DOSBox but I failed on doing that. DOSBox keeps printing a the follwoing message:

"cannot run this program in dos mode"

I tried this on both, MAC and Ubuntu versions of DOSBox.

Comment: MASM **version 11** :   ( http://www.masm32.com/installation.htm ) `The MASM32 SDK is designed to install on Windows operating system versions from WIN2000 upwards.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `MASM` in `DOSBox` you need a `DOS` version of MASM. It is very old one.

The version you are trying to use is for Windows and supposed to be used as console `i386` application.

Comment: Searching for the latest MSDOS version of MASM 5.10 (including a 16 bit linker) using the search term of "masm51.zip" i found this page:
http://microprocessados.lesc.ufc.br/downloads/Laboratorio/masm51.zip